# Grouping by subqueries

Tags: sql-server, group-by, subquery

Need some help here. Check the last GROUP BY clause.

```
set nocount on
--Creo variable de tabla sin duplicados
Declare @Temp1 Table (nro_viaje nvarchar(255),cod_cliente nvarchar(255))
if object_id('tempdb..#Temp2') is not null
Begin
 drop table #Temp2
End
if object_id('tempdb..#ProcesadosBrutos') is not null
Begin
 drop table #ProcesadosBrutos
End


insert into @Temp1 (nro_viaje,cod_cliente)
select distinct [nro_viaje],cod_cliente FROM [Test].[dbo].[Hoja1$] order by nro_viaje
--Remuevo los viajes que fueron de un solo cliente
Delete T
From @Temp1 T
JOIN (select nro_viaje, count(*) cant from @Temp1 group by nro_viaje having COUNT(*)=1) S on T.nro_viaje=S.nro_viaje
--Numero los viajes para iterar

select cod_cliente,nro_viaje, dense_rank()over ( order by nro_viaje) as ViajeID into #Temp2 from @Temp1  

--Obtengo el menor viaje para comenzar a iterar
Declare @ViajeID int
Declare @ViajeIDMax int
Select @ViajeID=Min(ViajeID) From #Temp2
Select @ViajeIDMax=MAX(ViajeID) From #Temp2

Create Table #ProcesadosBrutos (Cod_cliente nvarchar(255), Combinables nvarchar(4000), Cantidad nvarchar (255))

While @ViajeID<=@ViajeIDMax --Itero por cada viaje
Begin

Insert into #ProcesadosBrutos (Cod_cliente,Combinables, Cantidad)
SELECT DISTINCT ST2.cod_cliente ,
    SUBSTRING(
        (
            SELECT '-'+CONVERT(varchar,ST1.cod_cliente)  AS [text()]
            FROM #Temp2 ST1
            WHERE
                ST1.ViajeID=@ViajeID 
                  and   ST1.viajeid = ST2.viajeid
            and ST1.cod_cliente <> ST2.cod_cliente
            ORDER BY ST1.cod_cliente
            FOR XML PATH ('')
        ), 2, 1000) COMBINABLES,
        (SELECT count(*) FROM #Temp2 TMP2 WHERE ST2.nro_viaje = TMP2.nro_viaje GROUP BY nro_viaje) Cantidad
 FROM #Temp2 ST2 
where ViajeID=@ViajeID --AND (SELECT count(*) FROM #Temp2 TMP2 WHERE ST2.nro_viaje = TMP2.nro_viaje GROUP BY nro_viaje) > 1 AND (SELECT count(*) FROM #Temp2 TMP2 WHERE ST2.nro_viaje = TMP2.nro_viaje GROUP BY nro_viaje) < 4
group by (SELECT count(*) FROM #Temp2 TMP2 WHERE ST2.nro_viaje = TMP2.nro_viaje GROUP BY nro_viaje)
ORDER BY ST2.cod_cliente
--Aumento en 1 el viajeid para proxima iteracion
      Set @ViajeID=@ViajeID+1
End


Select distinct * from #ProcesadosBrutos order by Cod_cliente
```

Im getting the following error: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

I need to group by the results given by the subquery "(SELECT count(*) FROM #Temp2 TMP2 WHERE ST2.nro_viaje = TMP2.nro_viaje GROUP BY nro_viaje)".

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: You could try to GROUP BY on the alias `cantidad` or if that does not work, you will have to use a sub query for your current main query and apply then last group by (then again against the new alias)

Comment: yup i've tried grouping by the alias. gonna try your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing the GROUP BY with your alias?

```
GROUP BY Cantidad
```

Comment: You can't use a column alias in the group by clause.  This is a consequnce of the [logical processing order](https://destinationdata.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/the-logical-processing-order-3/).  The group by is processed before the select clause, meaning the alias won't exist at that point.   Instead you can turn the query into a sub query and then group by the required field.  Or you could use CROSS APPLY to generate the required field earlier in the query.